# Function to add user inputs to a list

Tags: python, list, function, loops, input

I've been having some trouble getting the logic to work properly for the below function:

```
def answers_body():
   user_preference = []
   user_preference.extend(input("Please enter your answer: "))
```

My question really comes down to; how can I re-write this so the list doesn't get cleared each time it's called? I'm avoiding using Global Variables for this program; due to this, I'd really appreciate any more experienced programmers giving some advice on how to rectify this without resorting to a global variable/list.

Thank you.

Comment: `preference_list.append` + define list in arguments like `def answers_body(preference_list=[])`

Comment: So if I define the list in the function arguments I can keep adding to it? i.e if I ran answers_body twice, both answers would exist within the list after two runs?

EDIT: This worked! Thank you very much :). One last question; if I wanted to pull the list from this function in future, how would I go about that? Python throws an undefined error when I try and print outside the function.

Comment: It's not in the global namespace, so you have to return it and get it like this: `user_preference = answers_body()`

Answer (score 2):

One way is to place `preference_list` outside of your function call. And I would recommend you to use `list.append` instead because `list.extend` is mainly used to add multiple values to list.

```
preference_list = []
def answers_body(body):
    body.append(input("Please enter your answer: "))
for i in range(10):
    answers_body(preference)
print(preference_list)
```

You can also save `preference_list` into `answers_body`'s namescope if you don't what it as a global variable.

```
def answers_body():
    answers_body.preference_list.append(input("Please enter your answer: "))

answers_body.preference_list = []
for i in range(10):
    answers_body()
print(answers_body.preference_list)
```

Comment: how about pass the list as a function paramater?

Comment: Is there anyway to do this without making it a global variable? Or is it a lost cause; and I should investigate a different way to save users inputs from multiple runs of the function?

Comment: @pixelrain You can use the new way to not make it a global variable